# Is CORS request without Origin allowed?

Tags: cors

Is it correct that a request without "Origin" in header versus a CORS protected resource Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to a specific fqdn receive a correct 200 response?

I was expecting an error like when Origin is set to a different fqdn than the one allowed, while it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you observing a web browser not send the Origin header? CORS is enforced by the browser. Servers may or may not pay attention to the Origin header.

Comment: No I'm doing a request directly to the resource protected by CORS from browser and if I specify Origin in header it's blocked, but if I don't specify Origin at all it works, so I was wondering if this is correct or not.

Comment: You can't override the Origin header in a CORS AJAX request (unless maybe if the server specifies Origin in Access-Control-Allow-Headers, which would be strange and probably a security hole). The Origin header is automatically set by your browser for CORS requests. If this isn't what your question is about, please include a code example because it's unclear what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CORS protection is designed to prevent one website triggering activity on another website using your credentials, e.g. a script on A.com posting data to B.com via an AJAX request.

The Origin header is automatically set by the browser (and cannot be overridden) if a site triggers a request to a different domain*. This is checked against the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on the second site.

If you are directly accessing B.com in a browser then Origin will be blank because you are on the same site: CORS is not relevant. Manually setting an Origin header will mimic the restriction behaviour but it's not the normal scenario that CORS is designed to protect the user from.

*Certain types of request (such as loading images or scripts) are not blocked by CORS protection

Comment: So, that explains why Python scripts or somethings can make requests to any site and read the response, but not one website to another. Thanks, i has been thinking about it the whole time in my shower yesterday.

Comment: is there a resource that makes me feel sure about this topic?